# Obtaining k-order statistics by row from a proximity matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, random-forest, proximity

After obtaining a proximity matrix from randomForest, for each row/observation in the data set I would like to find the k-nearest points (excluding the observation itself, or, equivalently, the diagonal elements of the proximity matrix) and then their true class labels. I know how to find the indices of the max or min of each row in a matrix but I do not know how to program R to exclude the diagonal elements and to identify the k greatest entries by row.

```
> set.seed(1234)
> d <- iris[sample(nrow(iris), 6, replace = FALSE),]
> iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=d, ntree=2000, proximity=TRUE, oob.prox=TRUE)
> m <- iris.rf$proximity
> m
           18        93        91        92       126       149
18  1.0000000 0.7486911 0.7653631 0.7500000 0.2620690 0.4723926
93  0.7486911 1.0000000 0.7836257 0.7329545 0.5497076 0.2763819
91  0.7653631 0.7836257 1.0000000 0.6795580 0.5371429 0.2289157
92  0.7500000 0.7329545 0.6795580 1.0000000 0.3107345 0.4535519
126 0.2620690 0.5497076 0.5371429 0.3107345 1.0000000 0.8115942
149 0.4723926 0.2763819 0.2289157 0.4535519 0.8115942 1.0000000

> which(m[1,] == max(m[1,]), arr.ind = TRUE)
18 
 1
```

Comment: SO is about helping. Please write a reproducible example, which include a subset of your dataset and the code you have been working on.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it on my own, although if there is a way to improve the code (or if there is an error) I would appreciate the feedback.

```
f = function(d,k){
m <- randomForest(y ~ ., data=d, ntree=2000, proximity=TRUE, oob.prox=TRUE)$proximity
diag(m) <-0
tmp <- lapply(as.list(as.data.frame(m)),order,decreasing = TRUE)
tmp1 <- t(as.data.frame(tmp))[,c(1:k)]
class.mat <- matrix(data=NA,nrow(d), k, byrow=TRUE)

for(i in 1:nrow(d)){

    class.mat[i,] = d$y[tmp1[i,]]
}
return(class.mat)
}
```